# UI slow at updating ObservableCollection<T> in TreeView control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

#### Scenario

I have a `TreeView` that is bound to `ObservableCollection<T>`. The collection gets modified every time the end-user modifies their filters. When users modify their filters a call to the database is made (takes 1-2ms tops) and the data returned gets parsed to create a hierarchy. I also have some XAML that ensures each `TreeViewItem` is expanded, which appears to be part of the problem. Keep in mind that I'm only modifying ~200 objects with a max node depth of 3. I would expect this to instant.

#### Problem

The problem is that whenever filters get modified and the `TreeView` hierarchy gets changed the UI hangs for ~1 second.

Here is the XAML responsible for create the `TreeView` hierarchy.

```
<TreeView VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Hierarchy}" Width="240"
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Row="1">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <!-- Hierarchy template -->
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Stations}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
            <!-- Station template -->
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Locates}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <!-- Locate template -->
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TicketNo}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

And here is the code for updating the list.

```
public ObservableCollection<HierarchyViewModel> Hierarchy
{
    get { return _hierarchy; }
    set { _hierarchy = value; }
}

public void UpdateLocates(IList<string> filterIds)
{
    _hierarchy.Clear();

    // Returns 200 records max    
    var locates = _locateRepository.GetLocatesWithFilters(filterIds);
    var dates = locates.Select(x => x.DueDate);

    foreach (var date in dates)
    {
        var vm = new HierarchyViewModel
        {
            DueDate = date
        };
        var groups = locates.Where(x => x.DueDate.Date.Equals(date.Date)).GroupBy(x => x.SentTo);

        // Logic ommited for brevity

        _hierarchy.Add(vm);
    }
}
```

I also have `<Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />` as a style. I have tried using a `BindingList<T>` and disabling notifications, but that didn't help.

Any ideas as to why my UI hangs whenever changes are made to the `ObservableCollection<T>`?

#### Partial Solution

With what H.B. said and implementing a `BackgroundWorker` the update is much more fluid.

Comment: How intensive is the `// Logic omitted for brevity`?

Comment: How much work is being done in the `// Logic ommited for brevity` code, and is this being done on the UI thread? You mention that the db call is very fast, but could this code be a bottleneck?

Comment: Are you sure that `UpdateLocates` is called only once when filters are changed?

Comment: I'm no XAML expert, but the original TreeView control for Windows Forms had a BeginUpdate() and EndUpdate() method, which would stop repainting the control for any code that updated the treeview between these method calls. Maybe the XAML TreeView has these methods as well ?

Comment: The logic I omitted is not the bottleneck as far as I can see from testing. And yes, `UpdateLocates` is only called once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is probably the `foreach` loop. Every time you add an object the `CollectionChanged` event is fired and the tree is rebuilt.

You do not want to use an `ObservableCollection` if all you do is clear the whole list and replace it with a new one, use a `List` and fire a `PropertyChanged` event once the data is fully loaded.

i.e. just bind to a property like this (requires implementation of [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)):

```
private IEnumerable<HierarchyViewModel> _hierarchy = null;
public IEnumerable<HierarchyViewModel> Hierarchy
{
    get { return _hierarchy; }
    set
    {
        if (_hierarchy != value)
        {
            _hierarchy = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Hierarchy");
        }
    }
}
```

If you set this property bindings will be notified. Here i use the `IEnumerable` interface so no-one tries to just add items to it (which would not be noticed by the binding). But this is just *one* suggestion which may or may not work for your specific scenario.

(*Also see sixlettervariable's good comment*)

---

Just a side note, this code:

```
public ObservableCollection<HierarchyViewModel> Hierarchy
{
    get { return _hierarchy; }
    set { _hierarchy = value; }
}
```

is bad, you could overwrite the list and the binding would break because there is no [PropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) event being fired in the setter.

If you use an ObservableCollection it normally is used like this:

```
private readonly ObservableCollection<HierarchyViewModel> _hierarchy =
            new ObservableCollection<HierarchyViewModel>();
public ObservableCollection<HierarchyViewModel> Hierarchy
{
    get { return _hierarchy; }
}
```

Comment: +1, Alternatively he could use the `foreach` but do it in two parts. One part would make all the VMs, one part would add all the VMs. Another possibility is a custom collection which is `INotifyCollectionChanged` and implements an appropriate `AddRange`.

Comment: Nice answer. +1

I don't think the list constantly firing events is the issue. Making `Hierarchy IList and notifying the UI once the list is complete is just as slow. I think it has to do with the fact I expand every `TreeViewItem` node. Taking the XAML responsible for expanding the nodes *appears* to be faster but it's hard to tell while only seeing the first depth of nodes.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is detach the item you are bound to, make all the changes you need to the list, then reattach it.

For example, set the treeviews ItemsSource to NULL/NOTHING, run through your for each, then set the ItemsSource back to _hierarchy.  Your adds will be instant.